# K8S: a tunnel between a pod and a node

Tags: kubernetes

I need to deploy an application which works as a CCM (cloud controller manager), so it needs to have access to the master servers.

I have a K8S cluster that has been set up by Kubespray, all my nodes are running `kubelet` that takes configuration from `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf`. The `kubelet.conf` is shown below:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: ***
    server: https://localhost:6443
  name: default-cluster
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default-cluster
    namespace: default
    user: default-auth
  name: default-context
current-context: default-context
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: default-auth
  user:
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
```

This configuration file and the certificates are being provided to the CCM service, I added the following volumes and mountpoints to the deployment YAML:

```
      containers:
      - name: cloud-controller-manager
        image: swisstxt/cloudstack-cloud-controller-manager:v0.0.1
        # Command line arguments: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/command-line-tools-reference/cloud-controller-manager/
        command:
        - /root/cloudstack-ccm
        - --cloud-provider=external-cloudstack
        - --cloud-config=/config/cloud-config
        - --kubeconfig=/var/lib/kubelet/kubelet.conf # Connection Params
        - --v=4
        volumeMounts:
        - name: config-volume
          mountPath: /config
        - name: kubeconfig-config-file
          mountPath: /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet.conf
        - name: kubernetes-pki-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/kubelet/pki
        - name: kubernetes-config-volume
          mountPath: /var/lib/kubernetes
      volumes:
      - name: config-volume
        configMap:
          name: cloud-controller-manager-config
      - name: kubeconfig-config-file
        hostPath:
          path: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
      - name: kubernetes-pki-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/kubelet/pki
      - name: kubernetes-config-volume
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/kubernetes
```

So far, so good.

My problem is that my `kubelet.conf` is having the following sentence: `.clusters.cluster.server: https://localhost:6443`. So, `kubelet` is configured to interact with the master servers via a proxy-server that has been set up by Kubespray to distribute the connections between the master services.

So, when the CCM application inspect the `kubelet.conf` it understands that it should communicate with the master servers via `https://localhost:6443`, but inside of the pod of this application `localhost:6443` is not being listened by this proxy server, so CCM can't use `localhost:6443` to communicate with the master server, as `localhost:6443` is accessible only from the node itself.

Here's the question: is there a way to make the node's `localhost:6443` accessible from the pod? The only idea I have at this moment is to set up an SSH-tunnel between the pod and the node it's running at, but I don't like it, because (1) it requires to propagate some RSA-key on all the nodes and add it on every new node, (2) I have no idea on how to find out the IP-address of the node from behalf of a container.

Thanks for reading this rant. I'll be very grateful for all the ideas and clues.

Comment: Found a workaround for the CCM application: it allows to add the `--master` parameter which overrides the `.clusters[0].cluster.server`, so I added `--master=https://kubernetes.default.svc/` as a parameter of the application and now it works fine.

Though this workaround doesn't answer to my question on how to implement a tunnel between a pod and the node it's running on.

Comment: You are using your own CCM or Kubernetes one?

Comment: @Crou, this one, to be exact: https://github.com/swisstxt/cloudstack-cloud-controller-manager